# SpriteNodes stop moving in the middle of the screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm building a game using spriteKit.

I created a spriteNode called 'planet' and set a velocity. It drops down from the top of the screen with constant speed to the bottom of the screen. However, it slows down towards the middle of the screen and stops moving entirely. I added the method 'moveTowardPosition' as an attempt to fix this issue by forcing the objects to move offscreen. Does anyone have an idea of what the issue might be?

Thanks!

Here is the setup of the object:

```
-(void)physicsBodySetup
{

//initializes the physicsBody
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:40];
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

//sets its category mask
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = TKCollisionCategoryPlanet;

//planet doesn't collide with anything
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

//the planet can get into contact with an astranaut
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = TKCollisionCategoryAstronaut |            

}

//adds 'planet' to the screen at random position

//@param frame: the frame of the main view

-(void)addPosition:(CGRect)frame

{

//specifies a random position to add the planet on the screen
float randomPositionY = frame.size.height + self.size.height;
float randomPositionX = [TKUtil randomWithMin:10+self.size.width max:frame.size.width-10 - self.frame.size.width];
self.position = CGPointMake(randomPositionX, randomPositionY);
[self velocitySetup];
}

-(void)velocitySetup
{
//initializes the speed to be a constant
self.planetSpeed = TKPlanetSpeed;
self.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, self.planetSpeed);
}

//@param position: the point of planet on the screen

-(void)moveTowardsPosition:(CGPoint)position

{

float offScreenX = position.x;
float offScreenY = position.y - 2000;
CGPoint pointOffScreen = CGPointMake(offScreenX, offScreenY);

float Distance = pointOffScreen.y - position.y;
float time = Distance / self.planetSpeed;
SKAction *movePlanet = [SKAction moveTo:pointOffScreen duration:time];
NSArray *sequence = @[movePlanet, [SKAction removeFromParent]];
[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:sequence]];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of friction is 0.2. So you can try:

```
self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0
```

now it won't be affected by surface anymore.

Comment: @user3776485 Your welcome, happy that it solved your problem, can you accept my answer please.